# The greatness of a teacher lies in respecting the child

Tags: teaching-methods, teaching

> **The  greatness  of  a  teacher  lies  in  respecting  the  child**

I think the  concept  of  Emerson's  is similar  to the  concept  of  the present  teaching scenorio which  claims  that  learnimng is neither  teacher  centered  nor  chilld centered  but  learning  centered in which  learning may take place  between teacher  to student or  student  to student.

*How  can we  apply this  quotion by  Emerson in the  teaching  learning  process  of  English*?

I think  though  it may sound  paradoxical, it  means  teachers  should  take  care  of  pupils' aspirations, needs  and  doubts  to  become  great.

I hope  I get   some good  answers which  are  not just  opinion based  but  relevant  to the  latest  teching methods.

Answer (score 0):

Maria Montessori has a lot on respecting the child "follow the child," etc., which might be useful to this question.

I'm not sure "respecting the child" is the same thing as "taking care of pupils' aspirations, needs and doubts to become great". That seems to be a fairly heavy interpretation.

For Montessori it is about allowing the child to unfold their own learning, in a way, instead of being taught didactically.